# Ordering groups/partition windows by other column values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a sample from a database I'm using in SQL server 2014 you can use here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0d98e/1
It looks like this

```
+--------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------+------------+----+
| Event_number |          Venue           |            Date             | Attendance | rn |
+--------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------+------------+----+
|          247 | Air Canada Centre        | September, 21 2013 00:00:00 |      15504 |  1 |
|          215 | Air Canada Centre        | September, 22 2012 00:00:00 |      16800 |  2 |
|          296 | Allphones Arena          | November, 08 2014 00:00:00  |       9904 |  1 |
|          200 | Allphones Arena          | March, 03 2012 00:00:00     |      14537 |  2 |
|          311 | American Airlines Center | March, 14 2015 00:00:00     |      17160 |  1 |
|          266 | American Airlines Center | March, 15 2014 00:00:00     |      19324 |  2 |
|          344 | Amway Center             | December, 19 2015 00:00:00  |      14459 |  1 |
|          270 | Amway Center             | April, 19 2014 00:00:00     |      17000 |  2 |
|          322 | Arena Ciudad de México   | June, 13 2015 00:00:00      |      21036 |  1 |
|          298 | Arena Ciudad de México   | November, 15 2014 00:00:00  |      21000 |  2 |
+--------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------+------------+----+
```

The table is about sporting events that have returned to the same venue. I found the two most recent times an event took place at each Venue from another table and partitioned the results by date desc and then I selected the first two rows to produce this sample data.

What I want to do is order this information by Venue pairs (rn 1 and 2), with the Date desc where rn = 1 without splitting up the pairs.

So the result I am looking for would look like this:

```
+--------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------+------------+----+
| Event_number |          Venue           |            Date             | Attendance | rn |
+--------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------+------------+----+
|          344 | Amway Center             | December, 19 2015 00:00:00  |      14459 |  1 |
|          270 | Amway Center             | April, 19 2014 00:00:00     |      17000 |  2 |
|          322 | Arena Ciudad de México   | June, 13 2015 00:00:00      |      21036 |  1 |
|          298 | Arena Ciudad de México   | November, 15 2014 00:00:00  |      21000 |  2 |
|          311 | American Airlines Center | March, 14 2015 00:00:00     |      17160 |  1 |
|          266 | American Airlines Center | March, 15 2014 00:00:00     |      19324 |  2 |
|          296 | Allphones Arena          | November, 08 2014 00:00:00  |       9904 |  1 |
|          200 | Allphones Arena          | March, 03 2012 00:00:00     |      14537 |  2 |
|          247 | Air Canada Centre        | September, 21 2013 00:00:00 |      15504 |  1 |
|          215 | Air Canada Centre        | September, 22 2012 00:00:00 |      16800 |  2 |
+--------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------+------------+----+
```

I came up with a pseudo solution which was to basically concatenate each pair of rows into a single row, which I could then order by one of the chosen date columns. But I want to know if it's possible to do it while retaining pairs and for any future queries where I might want to sort partitioned/windowed results by specific guidelines.

Thanks for any help. Please let me know if I didn't provide enough information or if I was unclear in my explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the the `max()` with an `over()` clause partitioned by `Venue` to get the max date for each venue and then use that as the first column in the order by clause.

```
select T.Event_number,
       T.Venue,
       T.Date,
       T.Attendance,
       T.rn
from (
     select S.Event_number,
            S.Venue,
            S.Date,
            S.Attendance,
            S.rn,
            max(S.Date) over(partition by S.Venue) as MaxDate
     from SampleTable as S
     ) as T
order by T.MaxDate desc,
         T.Venue,
         T.rn;
```

Comment: You don't even need a subquery: [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/78153/5) (it's Julien's query, your and yours without subquery)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` to get the `MAX(date)` for each Venue and then `ORDER BY` it:

```
SELECT Event_number, Venue, [Date], Attendance, rn
FROM dbo.SampleTable s
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT md = MAX([Date]) 
    FROM dbo.SampleTable 
    WHERE s.Venue = Venue
) ca
ORDER BY ca.md DESC, Venue, s.rn
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/78153/1/0)

By the way, you can insert into the sample table with 1 single insert:

```
INSERT [dbo].[SampleTable] ([Event_number], [Venue], [Date], [Attendance], [rn]) 
VALUES 
    (247, N'Air Canada Centre', CAST(N'2013-09-21 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 15504, 1)
    , (215, N'Air Canada Centre', CAST(N'2012-09-22 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 16800, 2)
    ...
```